# Cannot "deploy now" in EU?

Tags: jenkins, cloudbees

When I click "deploy now" on my webapp jenkins job, the account list is empty and region list only contains US. Did I miss something? Is it possible to deploy from jenkins to EU region?

For information I have created an application in EU with a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the "Deploy now" option you should be able to deploy in the US and also in the EU. It is due a confict with the credential plugin, you need to update this plugin and to restart your instance.

To do this, go to Manage Jenkins->Manage Plugins and in the Updates section check if you have the credential plugins. I have just tested with it, and it seems to be working properly.

Comment: My "CloudBees Deployer Plugin" is installed and with version 4.18. I tried a Tomcat 7 ClickStart but I have the same problem, only US! 

It seems to be filled with ajax request to com.cloudbees.plugins.deployer.impl.run.RunTargetImpl/fillApiEndPointItems and com.cloudbees.plugins.deployer.impl.run.RunHostImpl/fillAccountItems.

Maybe I have to set my default region somewhere?

Comment: Support team have fixed your issue. I have just updated the answer here.

Answer (score 0):

I created a support ticket and the problem was due to a plugin version conflict fixed by support (don't know more but support is very effective!).